# Is it a good way to count unique visitors?

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php

    $date = date("Y-m-d"); //Return current date in yyyy-mm-dd format
    $userIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];// Stores remote user ip address

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `unique_visitors` WHERE `date` = '$date'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

    if($result->num_rows == 0)// this block will execute when there is no record of current date in database
    {
        $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO `unique_visitors` (`date`,`ip`) VALUES ('$date','$userIP')";
        mysqli_query($connection,$insertQuery);
    }
    else
    {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();//Extracts result row from result object

        if(!preg_match('/'.$userIP.'/i',$row['ip']))//Will execute When Current ip is not in databse
        {
            $newIP = "$row[ip] $userIP"; //Combine previous and current user ip address with a separator for updating in database
            $updateQuery = "UPDATE `unique_visitors` SET `ip`='$newIP', `views`=`views`+1 WHERE `date` = '$date' ";
            mysqli_query($connection,$updateQuery);
        }
    }
?>
```

Is there a better way to count unique visitors in my website or this simple code is fine to insert into my website?

Comment: No, this code is wrong on so many levels. It would count anything but unique visitors. You need to start with basic SELECT queries.

Comment: can you give me a link to check?

Comment: the main problem here is that you are always checking only the first ip in the table, not all ips recorded.

Comment: Also note one `IP` does not signify one user. You can have hundreds of users behind one IP.

Comment: @user3783243 it doesn't really matter. "unique visitors" is always an arbitrary number, you never can have it exact, no matter what technique you'd try. Hence counting IPs is as good as anything else.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I think cookie usage would be somewhat more accurate.

Comment: @user3783243 and then you will need to add that annoying banner asking everyone to agree. From my experience, IP is good enough but you can use cookies if you wish, with all the false positives they introduce in turn.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the basic PHP/mysqli code for the approach you taken. You have to create an unique index for two fields, date and ip. And everything would work with just a single query.

```
<?php

$userIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];// Stores remote user ip address

$sql = "INSERT INTO unique_visitors (date, ip, views) VALUES (curdate(),?,1)
          ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE views = views + 1";
$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $userIP);
$stmt->execute();

$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM unique_visitors WHERE date = curdate()";
$result = $connection->query($sql);
$visitors = $result->fetch_row()[0];
```